# Python 3, sending an email through a Gmail hosted college account

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

so recently I have been trying to send emails using Python 3.6 through my college email account `my_email@my_college.edu`. This account is hosted on google, so I can use it with Gmail, Drive, etc. As such I thought it would be simple enough to write a simple program that would accomplish what I wanted, but nothing seems to be working. Here is the basic code that I found on practically every tutorial website:

```
import smtplib

TO = 'receiver_email'
SUBJECT = 'TEST MAIL'
TEXT = 'Here is a message from python.'

# Gmail Sign In
gmail_sender = 'my_email@my_college.edu'
gmail_passwd = 'my_password'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO,
                    'From: %s' % gmail_sender,
                    'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,
                    '', TEXT])

try:
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
    print ('email sent')
except:
    print ('error sending mail')

server.quit()
```

Whenever I run this, I get a "bad credentials" error. Specifically the error I get is this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Coding Files\Projects in Progress\autoEmail.py", line 14, in 
<module>
    server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not 
accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?
p=BadCredentials g8sm9220621qtg.23 - gsmtp')
```

I tried working with the Gmail API, and that was able to get me Gmail credentials and sign me in to a chrome page, but I couldn't seem to find a sufficient tutorial that I was able to understand using the Gmail API.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thank you

Comment: The problem is that GMail does not allow user/pass identification in the default configuration. You need to use oauth or to use what they call less secure apps configuration: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: The error message contains a link that explains what to do, https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials

Comment: I looked at the link, but I wasn't sure which problem was the relevant one for me. I now understand that it stems from insecure devices, but I'm still not sure if that is the best approach.

Comment: @wjmccann Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the server from `smtp.gmail.com` to `my_college.edu` (or maybe `something.my_college.edu`, or something like that). I've configured stuff that needs email server URLs with school Gmails and it worked like that, if I remember correctly.